# Can I call std::format with a consteval std::array as the format string?

Tags: c++, c++20, consteval, stdformat

I have a consteval `std::array` that contains a format string:

```
consteval std::array<char, 3> make_consteval_format_string()
{
    return std::array<char, 3> {'{', '}', '\n'}; // "{}\n"
}
```

I can convert this array to `std::string_view` and invoke `std::vformat`

```
template<typename Arg>
std::string format_arg(Arg&& arg)
{
    auto fmt_array = make_consteval_format_string(); // "{}\n"
    std::string_view str{ fmt_array.data(), fmt_array.size() }; // I would like to avoid this line
    return std::vformat(str, std::make_format_args(std::forward<Arg>(arg))); // I would like to call std::format
}
```

This works just fine:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s1 = format_arg(123);
}
```

However, the format string is fully known at compile time, its just that I can't figure out if I can somehow convert it to `std::format_string` and call `std::format` instead:

```
template<typename Arg>
std::string format_arg(Arg&& arg)
{ 
    // this is what I wish to do
    return std::format(make_consteval_format_string(), std::make_format_args(std::forward<Arg>(arg)));
}
```

So can I convert a `consteval std::array` to something that `std::format` will accept?

Comment: Why does the function have to return a std array of char? The name `make_consteval_format_string` already suggests it returns a string. It seems like it should just return a string. (I think you are making your own problems here)

Comment: this is a simplified code. I do a few string concatenation at compile time.

Comment: Still, you could as well have the function return a string_view, as that has constexpr constructors.

Comment: To start with...`make_format_args` should not be used when you are calling `std::format`?

Answer (score 2):

You can call `std::format` by converting `std::array` to `std::string_view` at compile time and passing the latter as a format string:

```
template<typename Arg>
std::string format_arg(Arg&& arg) {
  static constexpr auto fmt = make_consteval_format_string();
  return std::format(std::string_view(fmt.data(), fmt.size()), arg);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/55d38EfTq